# Updating read/unread table upon post insertion

Tags: mysql, database, foreign-keys

I'm trying to create a separate table that would track read/unread posts. Using `MySQLi` I will have two tables `items` and `items_tracking`. When the page is rendered it will join the the tables and check if the user read the posts or not.

```
items
+-------+------------+----+
|  id   | created_by | .. |
+-------+------------+----+
| item1 | id12       | .. |
| item2 | id433      | .. |
+-------+------------+----+

items_tracking
+---------+---------+------+
| user_id | item_id | read |
+---------+---------+------+
| id1     | item1   |    0 |
| id2     | item2   |    0 |
| id94    | item1   |    1 |
+---------+---------+------+
```

Now the idea was that whenever a new item/post is created in the `items` table, it will also create rows in the `items_tracking` table for all users and with column `read = 0`. Problem is, I have no idea how to work around this since the foreign key I would use in `items_tracking` is still pretty much undetermined.

Any ideas on how to approach inserting in both tables at the same time, while the second table references the first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need records with read=0 in the tracking table.

```
SELECT ..., t.read FROM items i LEFT JOIN items_tracking t ON (t.item_id = i.id)
```

This query will work even if there is no corresponding record in `items_tracking`; in this case, t.read in the result will be `NULL`. You only need to insert the records with `read = 1`, although you don't need even this flag, you test for `t.item_id IS NOT NULL` to see if you have a record in `items_tracking`.

Comment: Gah, you're right! I was so immersed in the problem I couldn't think of such a simple solution. But, what if you wanted to list only the unread items. How to select/show only those items that have non-existent counterparts in the `items_tracking` table? I think I would solve it by doing a `SELECT` on the `items` table and then for each of the item, I would do another `SELECT` finding out if a row in the `items_tracking` table exist, and if not, I wouldn't even render it. Correct?

Comment: `SELECT ... FROM items i LEFT JOIN items_tracking t ON (t.item_id = i.id) WHERE t.item_id IS NULL`